# NextJS Different Layouts for nested Routes

Tags: dynamic, layout, next.js, jsx, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have different nested routes in my project for example:

- / (that means if it's not a nested route like / (index) or /about )
- blog
- Profile

And all these routes need a different layout (navbar/sidebar, and maybe head and body)
But I don't know what's the best practice to implement this is.
And all these routes contain both dynamic and static routes.

Comment: Have you had a look at the official documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts? Did you have any issues implementing the approach suggested there?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/